# Are there alternatives to Facebook's Graph API deprecated User fields "locale" and "timezone"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-graph-api-v2.7

I am helping develop a **chatbot** for **Facebook Messenger** which uses Facebook's Graph API v2.6. But now Facebook is asking us to submit the app for review.

The problem is that our app asks the API for, among other things, the user's **locale** and **timezone**. I need the user's locale just to decide which **language** the bot uses to talk to the user. But now, since **Graph API v2.7**, both locale and timezone fields are **deprecated** and I don't know how to fetch the user's language and timezone, nor which **permissions** I need, so as to include them in the app review.

I searched the web for alternatives to those fields but I found nothing. What do I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile#fields explains what fields you can get via the Messenger Profile API (different from Graph API).

`locale` should be available via the `pages_user_locale` permission, and `timezone` via `pages_user_timezone`.

You will need to get those reviewed before you can use them:

> Beginning July 26, 2018, apps must request access to all other profile fields as part of the app review process. To submit for access to profile fields, add the permissions you would like to request when you submit your app in the Messenger Platform tab of the app console.